# CSS - a:visited:hover?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

How can I apply a font `color` only to hyperlinks which have already been `visited` and are being `hover` by the mouse?

Essentially, what I want to do is

```
a:visited:hover {color: red}
```

Comment: This appears to work in FF but not IE 6. Any work around for IE 6?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes that is possible.

Here’s an example:

```
<style type="text/css">
    a:link:hover {background-color:red}
    a:visited:hover {background-color:blue}
</style>

<a href="http://www.google.com/">foo</a><a href="http://invalid/">bar</a>
```

Comment: Is it supported in all browsers. Doesn't seem to work in Firefox 3.5

Comment: Worked for me on FFox 3.5 and IE7, but not IE6.

Comment: You may drop IE6 support if your user base is in the US. Even IE7 is used by less than 1% in the US www.theie7countdown.com

Answer (score 4):

There is a css declaration order for this to work properly as was mentioned earlier, although it didn't cover this particular option, it does make a difference. I've tested this on Chrome.

The order is

```
    a:link { color: red; }
    a:visited { color: blue; }
    a:visited:hover { color: yellow; }
    a:hover { color: green; }
    a:active { color: gray; }
```

It will work whether it comes before or after a:hover as long as both a:hover and a:visited:hover are after a:visited and before a:active. I just prefer to keep the two visited links together and the two hovers together.

Answer (score 2):

there is a sequence between link css to take effect..
a:hover must come after a:link and a:visited and a:active must come after a:hover
for more details refer below link..

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Comment: While that is good advice in general, it isn't applicable to this question. There is nothing in the question to mention the order (or existence) of other pseudo applied to a elements and  `a:visited:hover` is more specific then any of the selectors you mention in the answer (and the question isn't the rule not applying in IE6, not about it overriding other rules).

Comment: Dear Quentin i appreciate your comment but the solution which i post is most common problem which is face by many people even i also face the same sequencing problem after i correct it and i posted it because other people do not face the same problem.

Comment: While it is a common problem, it is not the problem being asked about.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I was unable to style just `color` on `a:visited:hover` (Chrome/FF) without declaring a background for `:link:hover` (anything other than `none` or `inherit` seems to work, I used `rgba()` for alpha sake).

For this to work in Chrome/FF:

```
a:visited:hover {
    color: #f00;
}
```

... (something like) this must be present:

```
a:link:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
```