# Combining multiple pseudo-selectors

Tags: html, css

It appears that at one point in time combining multiple pseudo-selectors was possible. For example, one could do this:

`a:visited:hover {color: red}`

A quick Google search reveals multiple examples of this in action, [here](http://webdesign.maratz.com/lab/visited_links_styling/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337033/css-avisitedhover), and [here](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=55400). I am unable to get this feature to work in the latest versions of Safari, Firefox, or Chrome. Can anyone explain why this feature has regressed and/or been handicapped?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `:visited` pseudoclass can't be used for most styling in a lot of modern browsers anymore because it's a security hole. See [this link](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/) for a more formal discussion on it.

The short version is that if you can style `:visited` links differently, you can use that to determine if people have visited various sites, and therefore target them based on their browser history. Most modern browsers therefore heavily restrict the styling that can be done on them.

You can still chain pseudoselectors. For example, `a:focus:hover` works just fine to apply styles only if the element is focused AND hovered. See [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/Szwv6/) for a demonstration.

Comment: I don't think you can use multiple pseudo selectors. Your demo doesn't work for me.

Comment: It works fine (in Chrome, at least); click in the demo area, press tab to focus the link, then hover it to see it become bolded.