# Chained pseudo classes (:visited:hover) do not work for different text-shadow

Tags: css

I have this stylesheet in mind:

```
a {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none; 
}

a:visited {
  color: #b30000;
}

a:link:hover {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255, 76, 76, 0.25); 
}

a:visited:hover {
  color: #b30000;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(192,0,0,0.25); 
}
```

But the browsers I tested won't use darker shadow for visited and hover. 
(Firefox 37.0.2 and Chrome 42.0.2311.152 64-bit, both on OS X 10.10.3)

I assume these classes are written correctly, since when I add different `background` for them, it works. But not for `text-shadow`... What am I missing?

EDIT 1: I have read [this suggested question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025297/combining-multiple-pseudo-selectors) but that answer can be more explicit. Since I can't suggest edit or even comment, I'll write my own answer after I made my workaround. Should I put it here or under that question?

EDIT 2: **TLDR**: It's just that `:visited` is so constrained as explained by [this Mozilla post](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/) that `text-shadow` can't be used with it.

Comment: Maybe you just don't see the shadow. Change all of the 1px to 2px. 1px shadows are hard to notice.

Comment: NendoTaka I'm nearing my head to the screen so much that my nose can touch it. I'm pretty sure it does not work as I intended, and the correct part of it works just the way I want.

Comment: what is the problem you can't see text-shadow?

Comment: The above css works for me I don't know why it does not work for you. I cut and paste your code to something and had no issues.

Comment: @NendoTaka are you sure you are seeing different color of `text-shadow` in different links? What platform are you using?

Comment: I can see you are using `0` for `blur-radius`  that;s why you are not able to see shadow. check this link. http://jsbin.com/buwixuzixi/1/edit

Comment: @KheemaPandey I can see them, but the problem is that I set different colors for visited and unvisited but the browser simply use that of unvisited for all links.

Comment: So it turns out that you CAN'T use `text-shadow` in any css with `:visited` as a "security" feature. Wow thats actually kind of funny.

Comment: @KheemaPandey Blur radius has nothing to do with this problem. It's just that `text-shadow` can't be used with `:visited`.

Comment: @VirgilMing you are right; with `:visited` text-shadow won't work.

Comment: @VirgilMing You can answer your own question below

Comment: @ThomasKilian By flagging as duplicate the moderator also closed the question so no answer can be added.

Comment: @VirgilMing of course. Stupid me :-(